# Second monitor resolution stopped working since recent upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

**Summary:**

My second monitor resolution has stopped working since recent upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04. From my (very limited) understanding, it looks like it no longer reads the text I have had in the .xprofile file.

**Details:**

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04. I have an second monitor (an old Dell) attached to the laptop. This monitor works best at 1920x1080. For the last couple of years, the only way I could have this working was by having the following text in an .xprofile file in the Home directory. But this was working fine.

*xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode "1920x1080"*

However, since the upgrade to 21.04, the second monitor as reverted to resolution 1024 x 768 and (looking in settings) only has resolutions "1024 x 768" and "800 x 600" available.

If I do xrandr in Terminal, I see that the external monitor is now called "XWAYLAND1", but even if I adapt the .xprofile text as below, it does not help.

*xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "1920x1080"*

Also, if I put the above three commands one after another straight into Terminal, I get the following error:

*X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
Value in failed request:  0x640
Serial number of failed request:  29
Current serial number in output stream:  29*

Can anyone advise?